# Cloudwatch error count not incrementing with errors caught in catch block

Tags: node.js, async-await, aws-lambda

I have an AWS lambda that has a handler that is async. The code is wrapped in a try....catch block. The catch block gets invoked becomes of an undeclared variable, yet I do not see the Error Count in CloudWatch error counts for this lambda increasing. What am I doing wrong?

```
//omitted require statements
module.exports.test= async (event) => {

try {

    var keyName = event.Records[0].s3.object.key;
    var bucketName = event.Records[0].s3.bucket.name;

    var arr;

    var params = {
        Bucket: bucketName,
        Key: keyName
    };

    var s3Promise = await s3.getObject(params).promise();

    var raw = s3Promise.Body.toString('ascii');


    let parsed = await simpleParser(raw);

    var csvInput = parsed.attachments[0].content.toString('ascii');


    var arr;

    arr = { datetime: moment().toISOString(), quantity: parseInt(jsonOutput[1][15], 10) } //jsonOutput is not defined

    const config = {
        id: 'test',

        quantity: {
            type: 'number',
            name: 'quantity'
        },
        datetime: {
            type: 'datetime',
            name: 'date'
        }
    }


    await findOrCreateAsync(config).then((response) => {
        const dataSetPutAsync = promisify(response.post)
        return dataSetPutAsync(arr)
    }).catch((err) => {
        throw new Error("error");
    })
} catch (err) {
    console.log("caught something!")
    return err;
}
```

};

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error Count is not incrementing, because all of your errors have been handle by you and your function is working fine.

It just counts uncaught error, If you want to count error when execute `findOrCreateAsync` function, let's change your code a bit.

Maybe, remove `try/catch` and `.catch` blocks, or do like this:

```
//omitted require statements
module.exports.test = async (event) => {

  try {

    var keyName = event.Records[0].s3.object.key;
    var bucketName = event.Records[0].s3.bucket.name;

    var arr;

    var params = {
      Bucket: bucketName,
      Key: keyName
    };

    var s3Promise = await s3.getObject(params).promise();

    var raw = s3Promise.Body.toString('ascii');


    let parsed = await simpleParser(raw);

    var csvInput = parsed.attachments[0].content.toString('ascii');


    var arr;

    arr = { datetime: moment().toISOString(), quantity: parseInt(jsonOutput[1][15], 10) } //jsonOutput is not defined

    const config = {
      id: 'test',

      quantity: {
        type: 'number',
        name: 'quantity'
      },
      datetime: {
        type: 'datetime',
        name: 'date'
      }
    }

    const response = await findOrCreateAsync(config);
    const dataSetPutAsync = promisify(response.post); // what?? response.post is a function with callback style ????
    return dataSetPutAsync(arr);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("caught something!");
    console.log(err);
    throw err; // noti to CloudWatch that function has been failed
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like these are not reported as error by lambda executor.

Some documentation from AWS.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-prog-mode-exceptions.html

Hence no error.